# Sharing single instance of class across multiple tests

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Page object pattern with selenium webdriver and testng.
I want to access instance of one page object class in another class across multiple `<test>`.

for e.g.

```
 <test name="Login scenario">
    <classes>
        <class name="sanitytests.LoginTests">
         <methods>
            <include name="validLogin"/>
         </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test> 

  <test name="scenario2" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
            <classes>
                 <class name="sanitytests.HomePageTests">
                 <methods>
                    <include name="clickOnMyAccountFromHome"/>
                 </methods>
                </class>
            </classes>
  </test>
```

in my LoginTests class I am using instance of homePage class

```
@Test()
    public void validLogin(ITestContext context) throws Exception {

    loginPage.loginDetails(username,password);
    homePage = loginPage.loginAsValidUser();
    context.setAttribute("homePage",homePage);

    }
```

my HomePageTests class

```
@Test()
    public void clickOnMyAccountFromHome(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
        homePage = (HomePage) context.getAttribute("homePage");
        myAccountPage = homePage.navigateToMyAccountPage();
        context.setAttribute("myAccountPage", myAccountPage);

    }
```

i am getting null pointer exception because `ItestContext` is used to share parameter between methods not between tests. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i have read about "ITestContext", it is related to TestNG classes/objects/methods. You can create the HomePage as a static and it will be available for entire suite run.

Answer (score 0):

The page object pattern does  not state that objects can only be created once. Create new instances in each test.